# Framework - TestNg with GEB

Tags: testng, geb

I am new to groovy and groovy but i have good experience in selenium.

Due to some requirement I was told to create framework in TestNG with GEB.

Does any one have sample framework in TestNG with GEB where I can get a hint and proceed with further.

As far as I explored,I found framework on gradle & cucumber.

Comment: https://github.com/savvagen/geb-testng-example Its using testng & geb

Comment: its using gradle & geb.

Comment: You need study difference between gradle and testng . Framework is using gradle+testng+geb https://github.com/savvagen/geb-testng-example/blob/master/build.gradle#L169